# Encoding a tree with serde_json

Tags: rust, serde

I'm new to Rust and have a project that requires specifying a config that is a tree. In JSON this would be like:

```
{
  "a": {
    "d": {
      "val": 10
    },
    "e": {
      val: 20
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "val": 5
  },
  "c": {
    "val": 1
  }
}
```

Here the root has 3 children "a,b,c" and "a" has two children "d,e" with one associated with the value 10 and another with the value 20 etc. In other words, the tree can have arbitrary depth and only leaf nodes have values associated.

My question: Is there a way to parse such a structure in Rust strait into some structs? What would be the cleanest way to parse something like this?

Comment: This is pretty vague and it really comes down to what data structure you WANT, based on how you need to use it. You _could_ parse this into a hashmap of hashmaps. You _could_ parse it into a hashmap where the keys are the the concatenation of the paths, e.g. `"a.d.val"`. You _could_ parse it into a radix tree. What is your actual need for this config once it is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the cleanest way to parse something like this?

That is dependent on your use-case, I'd say. I think the simplest solution would be to parse this into an untagged enum with either a leaf with a value, or a subtree. For the subtree a [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html) can be used. Here a simple example that can parse your json:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Node {
    Leaf { val: u8 },
    Tree(HashMap<String, Node>),
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"{
      "a": {
        "d": {
          "val": 10
        },
        "e": {
          "val": 20
        }
      },
      "b": {
        "val": 5
      },
      "c": {
        "val": 1
      }
    }"#;

    let tree: Node = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();

    let expect = Node::Tree(HashMap::from([
        (
            "a".to_owned(),
            Node::Tree(HashMap::from([
                ("d".to_owned(), Node::Leaf { val: 10 }),
                ("e".to_owned(), Node::Leaf { val: 20 }),
            ])),
        ),
        ("b".to_owned(), Node::Leaf { val: 5 }),
        ("c".to_owned(), Node::Leaf { val: 1 }),
    ]));

    assert_eq!(tree, expect);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa54ea3cca568e9f558643bf847d30f3)

But like I said, it depends what you want to do with the tree in your Rust code, whether this data structure is feasible for you or not.

Comment: The config is not used directly, but as an input into an algorithm that converts it to a cache efficient format (encodes it into an array). This probably works. Thanks!

Comment: @eof In that case, it would be more efficient to deserialize it directly into the structure needed for you algorithm, instead of using an intermediate structure.